# How to count the combinations of 2 columns? (Duplicate columns are also counted, not just counting distinct columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I am trying to count the combinations of 2 columns. Duplicate columns must also be counted. For example, I have this table called OrderedTogether. I want to count the combinations of Product1 and Product2 and any duplicate combinations of Product1 and Product2 should be counted as well. This count will then be a new column in the table called BoughtTogether. So for example, (24,28) and (8,33) should have 2 counts because there are 2 instances of this combination. The rest of the combinations should only have 1 count. How should I go about doing this?

[Image of OrderedTogether table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RQuW.png)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images or links to images. [mcve]

Comment: What about a simple groupiing `SELECT Product1, Product2, COUNT(*) FROM OrderedTogether GROUP BY Product1, Product2`

Answer (score 1):

This is a `CROSS JOIN` example - you want to create all pairs. I assumed that your table is a line item table so I could show how to write this query. So the first step I did was to create a table variable and populate it with your data:

```sql
DECLARE @LineItems AS TABLE (
    OrderID INT NOT NULL, 
    ProductID INT NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO @LineItems([OrderID],[ProductID])
VALUES
(10, 7), (10, 22), (10, 25), 
(12, 8), (12, 24), (12, 28), 
(11, 8), (11, 33), (12, 33), (11, 42), (9, 28), 
(9, 24), (9, 43), (9, 44);
```

With this in place, we can query out of `@LineItems`. The process is to `CROSS JOIN` the table to itself and only look at rows where the `OrderID` is the same. Also, so we don't get duplicate data we will only look at pairings where the first `ProductID` is less than the second `ProductID`. If this isn't done, there will be duplicate pairings - for example, if product1 is 45 and product2 is 59 we only want the pair once as (45, 59) - we don't want (59, 45) since it is the same pair. With all of this in place, the query is not too difficult:

```sql
SELECT   [li1].[ProductID] AS [Product1], [li2].[ProductID] AS [Product2], [li1].[OrderID]
FROM     @LineItems AS [li1]
         CROSS JOIN @LineItems AS [li2]
WHERE    [li1].[OrderID] = [li2].[OrderID]
         AND [li1].[ProductID] < [li2].[ProductID]
ORDER BY [li1].[ProductID], [li2].[ProductID], [li1].[OrderID];
```

This returns the results that are shown in your image:

| Product1 | Product2 | OrderID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 22 | 10 |
| 7 | 25 | 10 |
| 8 | 24 | 12 |
| 8 | 28 | 12 |
| 8 | 33 | 11 |
| 8 | 33 | 12 |
| 8 | 42 | 11 |
| 22 | 25 | 10 |
| 24 | 28 | 9 |
| 24 | 28 | 12 |
| 24 | 33 | 12 |
| 24 | 43 | 9 |
| 24 | 44 | 9 |
| 28 | 33 | 12 |
| 28 | 43 | 9 |
| 28 | 44 | 9 |
| 33 | 42 | 11 |
| 43 | 44 | 9 |